# Можно-ли передать ajax запрос другому сервлету?

Tags: javascript, ajax, java-ee, servlet

коллеги по опасному бизнесу!Просидел тьму времени над этим(Признаюсь сразу - не гуглил ничего)
Есть функционал,который должно реализовать мое тестовое серверное приложение.

> 1.Загрузка файла
>
> 2.Проверка на объем содержимого файла(размер)

На клиенте создал форму и js скрипт,который будет формировать ajax запросы.

На сервере стоит 3 сервлета.Один сервлет выступает в роли фильтра для файлов,которые необходимо загрузить.Второй сервлет - загрузка файла на сервер.Третий сервлет - берет количество обработанных байтов(работает вместе с progressListener) и отправляет json.

Клиент :

```
function upload(e){
e.preventDefault();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var formData = new FormData(document.forms.Form);
xhr.open("POST" , "http://localhost:8080/Sckoriy/Filter" , true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
            if(xhr.status == 413){
                alert("The uploading file is very large!")
            }
        }
    }
var xhr_GET = new XMLHttpRequest();
var answer = document.getElementById("Bar");
    xhr_GET.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr_GET.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
            if(xhr_GET.status == 200){
                    nswer.innerHTML = xhr_GET.responseText;
            }
        }   
    }
 xhr.upload.onprogress = function(){
 xhr_GET.open("GET" ,"http://localhost:8080/Sckoriy/CheckProgress" , true);
 xhr.responseType = "json";
 xhr_GET.send();
 }
 //GO!
 xhr.send(formData);
```

Сервер :

> 1.Сначала ajax на Filter.

```
  if(!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    return;
   };
    
   RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;     
   int length = request.getContentLength();
        if(length < MAX_REQUEST_LENGTH) {
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("Controller_0");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }else {
            response.sendError(REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE);
            response.flushBuffer();
    }
```

Если размер содержимого нормальный и enctype multipart/form-data,то пересылаем запрос на метод POST Controller_0

> 2.Логику сохранения файла на сервер я пожалуй упущу

При отправке файла на сервер наблюдаю следующую ситуацию :
На фильтр должен уйти был файл.Но все тело = null.
Если же убираю переходящее звено,то все работает так как предначертано.(Убираю фильтр)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю,что можно было и не делать фильтра,а в тот самый загрузочный сервлет всунуть такой код :

```
  if(!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request) ||        
      request.getContentLengthLong() > MAX_REQUEST_LENGTH) {
      response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE);
      return;
    };
```

Comment: А почему у меня первое слово не печатается?Я добрый вечер написал,а его нету

Comment: Фразы-приветствия автоматически удаляются за ненадобностью, потому что у некоторых вопрос короче, чем приветственная фраза

Comment: А разве `dispatcher.forward(request, response)` отправляет  POST запрос?